# Error: failed to get info about account, TypeError

Tags: testing

I'm working on a Localhost connection for unit testing. Just tried to request an airdrop and then get the account info but i'm getting the following error:

> Error: failed to get info about account xAueWjpd3UCTHWkVGheZRSo9FNEPMcfcY1z1XtVZzrP: TypeError: Expected a value of type `{jsonrpc,id,error} | {jsonrpc,id,error,result}` but received `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.10.30","slot":3},"value":{"data":["","base64"],"executable":false,"lamports":10000000000,"owner":"11111111111111111111111111111111","rentEpoch":0}},"id":"05906aac-da57-4c64-b9ac-e7bcefb6a65d"}`.

This is the code snippet that results in the following:

```
const LOCALHOST = "http://127.0.0.1:8899"
const confirmed: Commitment = "confirmed" as Commitment
const connection = new Connection(LOCALHOST, confirmed);
let authorityWallet: Keypair;
beforeEach(async () => {
    authorityWallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log(authorityWallet.publicKey.toBase58())
    const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(authorityWallet.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 10);
    console.log(signature)
    const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
    console.log(confirmation)
    console.log(await connection.getAccountInfo(authorityWallet.publicKey))
```

The console logs are as follows:

> xAueWjpd3UCTHWkVGheZRSo9FNEPMcfcY1z1XtVZzrP
> qvWEhq6c2NXac6CkZcxoifEBnZpWF1jZXWpkszgQpBQVbhuDutWVy3Ueq2kvykZ8qY3n2mZXQ9d5fxnTR7emBau
> { context: { slot: 3 }, value: { err: null } }

I'm not sure why there's a typeerror, would love to get some help. Do let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this error?

I'll suggest trying to airdropping smaller amounts. try 1 SOL at a time